# JAVA - return array elements between two points

Tags: java, arrays

I've been trying to make a code that goes through all array elements that are between two specified points, but I am stuck. 
Let's suppose it's an array like that:

```
int[][] new_array = new int[100][100];
```

And how do I get all elements that are in straight line between let's say

```
new_array[17][2];
```

and

```
new_array[5][90];
```

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: I forgot, here's an image of what I want to do
https://i.imgur.com/B27PFo3.png

Comment: Help us help you - please provide some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it.

Comment: It's not clear what should happen if the slope doesn't exactly line up with elements (i.e. interpolation, rounding, etc). For example, going from [0][0] to [1][2] isn't necessarily clear. You may however want to consider the [Bresenham Line Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) as a start, and potentially adapt it to your needs (or [Wu's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm) if you plan to interpolate/antialias anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine that your array is a [first quadrant](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/Cartesian_coordinates_2D.svg/240px-Cartesian_coordinates_2D.svg.png) of a cartesian coordinates system. With a first column lying on axis Y and last row lying on axis X.

Having that assumption you could find a function that describes a straight line between any of two points in your array.

You need to solve the function:

```
y = ax + b
```

It's a standard [linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function_(calculus)). You have two points, solving that you'll find your equation (values of `a` and `b`).

When you know equation you need to evaluate points in the array for each `x` value. Doing that you'll find all `y` values that are below/on/above the line.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Marcin Pietraszek's answer the function can be obtained this way:

Given the two points (a,b) and (c,d) the straight line that passes through both points is given by

```
a + K * (x - a) = c AND b + K (y - b) = d
```

where `K` is a scalar number.

And this resolves to:

`y` `=` `( (d - b) * x - (d - b) * a + (c - a) * b )` `/` `(c - a)`

So any point `(x, y)` that meets this condition will be on the straight line.

You will need go through the matrix, checking one by one to see which points meet the condition.

If you want only the point inside the segment, then aditionally you need to check the boundaries.